# Cannot Create New Directory Under C Drive and copy to it

Tags: batch-file, cmd, mkdir, xcopy

I'm writing a batch file to setup an environment for a project and I need to create a new directory directly under C: drive. Here's what I wrote. First I check that the file is being executed as Admin, then I check if the file already exists, if it doesn't, create it and go to it. Then I do other things.

```
  :check_Permissions
    echo Administrative permissons required. Detecting permissions...

    net session >nul 2>&1
    if %errorLevel% == 0 (
      echo Success : Administrative permissions confirmed.
    ) else (
      echo Failure : Current permissions inadequate.
      echo Please, run this file as administrator.
    )

    pause >nul

  if not exist "\C:\NewDir" (
    echo NewDir directory will be created under C: drive. 
    mkdir "\C:\NewDir"
    echo Created NewDir Folder under C: drive.
  ) else (
    echo Directory already exists.
    cd C:\NewDir
  )
  if not exist "\C:\NewDir" ( 
    echo Directory was not created. 
  )
  :next
```

I don't know why the directory is not created since the file is run as admin, it can't be for lack of permissions...

I also need to copy the contents of a remotely shared directory on another server into the newly created folder. XCOPY is not working. Here's the code:

```
  XCOPY /s "\\remoteserver\directory\sub-dir\directory-to-copy" "C:\NewDir"
```

Comment: `\C:\NewDir` is an invalid path as this means in root of current drive there should exist already or should be created a directory with name `C:` and next a subdirectory with name `NewDir`. A colon in a directory/file name is not allowed. Replace all `"\C:\NewDir"` by `"C:\NewDir"` and your batch file might work. Running in a command prompt window `md "\C:\Newdir"` results in output `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I changed \C:\NewDir to C:\NewDir and it now works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of what [BoogieMan2718](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7196523/boogieman2718) and [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564/mofi) said, I fixed my batch file. Here's the fixed verison :

```
:check_Permissions
  echo Administrative permissons required. Detecting permissions...

  net session >nul 2>&1
  if %errorLevel% == 0 (
    echo Success : Administrative permissions confirmed.
  ) else (
    echo Failure : Current permissions inadequate.
    echo Please, run this file as administrator.
  )

  pause >nul

cd C:\
if %cd% == "C:\" ( echo In C:\ drive. )

if not exist "C:\NewDir" (
  echo NewDir directory will be created under C: drive. 
  mkdir "C:\NewDir"
  echo Created NewDir Folder under C: drive.
  echo NewDir will now be copied to your computer. This action may take a few minutes...
  ROBOCOPY /E /V /Z "\\remoteServer\pathToDirectoryToCopy" "C:\NewDir"
) else (
  echo Directory already exists.
)
if not exist "C:\NewDir" ( 
  echo Directory was not created. 
)
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the batch file is saved and ran in the C:\ directory.

Also, try to see if you can create a test subdirectory under C:\ first. If this is not allowed, it may be a problem with directory ownership of C:\

As for the XCOPY, make sure you have the permission to copy from the remote shared directory.

Have you tried testing this in CMD step by step first?

Comment: I fixed a few things, I now use ROBOCOPY instead of XCOPY. The copy command works (I made a mistake -> "\C:" instead of "C:"). I added a command to redirect to C: (cd C:\). Now everything works fine!

Comment: @BoogieMan2718  Thanks for your answer! I was trying to clone a repo in C:\ but the dir was created in D:\ and further git commands on C:\myrepo gave me" "A subdirectory or file C:\myrepo" already exists"", i couldnt figure out why until i saw your answer. Had requested permission for my 'user' to have access to C:\ and BANG! I could clone in C:\ now!